# Scheduling tasks within a cluster of identical peers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, hazelcast

Given a simple web application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (i.e. 1..n identical instances behind a load balancer), how can I have a scheduled background operation that runs on one instance only?

I do have a cron-like scheduling mechanism within the web application, and could use e.g. AWS Simple Queue Service to queue tasks (and ensure that each task is executed just once). But how do I ensure that only one instance creates the tasks (to avoid duplicates)?

Obviously, I could have a dedicated instance that is in charge of creating tasks, but I'm looking for a more dynamic mechanism that lets one of the normal instances take on that role automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this could be accomplished using Hazelcast: Only the oldest node in the cluster (can be determined through the API) creates and queues tasks.

Answer (score 2):

[Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) works very well for us. Nodes come and go in our beanstalk, and Quartz manages to run the job on a node that happens to be up when the scheduler indicates that it needs to run. Supports cron-style scheduling as well as a couple of other formats. It is fault tolerant, and can run jobs that were missed because no instances were available when the task should have executed, or if a node failed to complete the execution.

Assumes that you're using RDS or some other relational DB that Quartz can use as a persistent store.

Comment: So is there a plug-in for Quartz that lets it detect running instances within an EC2 security group and coordinate job execution? Or how do you prevent duplicate job execution?

Comment: No plugin needed, just configuration. For instance, pointing all the nodes in your EC2 security group at the same database to store their Quartz job data would automatically make them coordinated. The Quartz agents on each node inspect the job details that are centralized in the database.

Comment: Thanks, found this: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09. Does look like you need either a relational database or Terracotta.

Comment: Exactly (that's what RDS is - MySQL or Oracle from Amazon)

Comment: You know that there is an implementation for dynamodb too: https://github.com/azam/dynamodb-quartz